# Spring ConstraintViolation not caught

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I'm using Spring Boot, and I have created a custom PathVariable validator, which I use as follows:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> test(@PathVariable("id")
                                     @Valid
                                     @MyGUID(message = "ID_INVALID")
                                             String id) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

The validor seems to do its job well - it passes when input is valid, and throws exception when not. The problem is, that my custom exception handler doesn't catch the `ConstraintViolationException` that is thrown. This is the top line of the stack trace:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: ID_INVALID
```

Then I have my exeception handler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = ConstraintViolationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException ex,
                                                                        HttpHeaders headers,
                                                                        HttpStatus status,
                                                                        WebRequest request) {
    List<String> errorDetailsCodes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
        errorDetailsCodes.add(violation.getMessage());
    }

    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(
            status.name(),
            status.value(),
            ex.hashCode(),
            errorDetailsCodes
    );

    logException(ex);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, headers, status);
}

@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleGeneralException(Exception ex) {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.name(),
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(),
            ex.hashCode()
    );

    logException(ex);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
}
```

It is strange to me that despite the fact I have both a specific and a general exception handler, they are both skipped, and the system throws its own error:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1568554746642,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "ID_INVALID",
  "path": "/api/logged-in-user/test/123"
}
```

How can I catch this exception and return my custom response?

Thanks.

Comment: If the exception is thrown during a Spring transaction (very likely), the constraint exception is wrapped in a `TransactionSystemException`. Maybe it could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446480/spring-boot-2-0-2-using-spring-data-how-do-i-get-message-from-entity-validation

Comment: It doesn' t help, I can't even import TransactionSystemException

Comment: In this case, posting the whole stracktrace could be more meaningful.